# While using struts html tags, How do I get the value of a textbox using its property attribute? Is there any other way to get the value?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts

```
    function validate(){
    var username = document.getElementByProperty("userName").value;
    var password = document.getElementByProperty("passWord").value;
    if((username == null ||username =='') || (password == null||password=='')){
     x=document.getElementById("error");
     x.innerHTML = "Username or Password Cannot Be Blank";
    else{
       document.getElementById("loginform").submit();
    }


    <form id="loginform" action="login.do" method="post">
    UserName:<html:text property="userName"></html:text>
    PassWord:<html:password property="passWord"></html:password>
    <html:button onclick="validate()"></html:button>
    </form>
```

the above code is not working and I am unable to get the values in textbox for validation... Please help me out in this issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function validate(){
    var username = document.getElementById("userName").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("passWord").value;
}


<form id="loginform" action="login.do" method="post">
    UserName:<html:text property="userName" styleId="userName"></html:text>
    PassWord:<html:password property="passWord" styleId="passWord"></html:password>
    <html:button onclick="validate()"></html:button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur respose Mr.Reddy... But, Struts-html tag doesn't have an 'id' attribute, that's why i'm asking about to get the value from property attribute.

Comment: I guess Struts has styleId rather than "id". Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Reddy... I have checked out by using 'styleid', it's working... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before reading next line, please install good web inspector.
e.g.

Firebug in Firefox

Web Inspector in Chrome

IE Web Inspector

and inspect the source

Or you can view the source.

```
   1. document.getElementsByName("userName")[0].value;
   2. document.getElementById("userName").value;
   3. document.forms["loginform"]["userName"].value
```